# Why does Odetta/Detta/Susannah not have prosthetic legs?

Tags: the-dark-tower

In the Drawing of the Three, we see that Odetta lost her legs after getting pushed on to train tracks. Since Odetta comes from a very rich family, why is it that she uses a wheelchair to get around and not prosthetic legs? Is it ever mentioned in the books if she chose to use a wheelchair on purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be because of the when.
Odetta was drawn in 1964 in a realistic world.
So even if her family was rich and her father an inventor, i don't think prostetics for both legs other than cosmetics would have been possible.